# Get list of interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, entity-framework-6

I am new to interfaces but I'm trying to force myself learn how to use them. I am confused on how to go about selecting a list of objects that implement an interface. This is the gist what I have so far:

```
public class Planet 
{
    public ICollection<Structure> Structures {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Ship> Ships {get;set;}
    public int GatherRate {get;set}
    public void GetAllResourceGatherers
    {
        var resourceGatherers = Planet.Ships.OfType<IResourceGatherer>()
                                                .ToList();

        //the below line doesn't work. I want to be able to get a list of all 
        //ships and structures that implement IResourceGatherer.    
        resourceStorers.AddRange(Structures.OfType<IResourceGatherer>()
                                               .ToList());

        foreach (var gatherer in resourceGatherers)
        {
            GatherRate += gatherer.GatherRate;
        }
    }
}
public class Ship
{
    //Stuff that all ships should have such as health, speed, cost, etc
}
public class Structure
{
    //Stuff that all structures should have such as buildtime, cost, etc
}
public class ResourceStructure : Structure, IResourceGatherer
{
    //implement interface
}
public class ResourceShip : Ship, IResourceGatherer
{
    //implement interface
}
interface IResourceGatherer
{
    int GatherRate{get;set;}
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and MVC 4 on this project.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Where iis resourceStorers defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
var resourceGatherers = new List<IResourceGatherer>();

var gathererShips = Planet.Ships.OfType<IResourceGatherer>().ToList();

var gathererStructures = Structures.OfType<IResourceGatherer>().ToList();

resourceGatherers.AddRange(gathererShips);
resourceGatherers.AddRange(gathererStructures);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are trying to get `IResourceGather` interface implementators from `Ships` property of a `Planet`. Note that property is of type `ICollection<Ship>`. Now tell me, does `Ship` implement `IResourceStorer`?

I bet it doesn't. That's why you get empty select result.

### According to the update:

Well, you are trying to get `IResourceGather` interface implementators from `Structures` property of a `Planet`. Note that property is of type `ICollection<Structure>`. Now tell me, does `Structure` implement `IResourceStorer`?

I bet it doesn't. That's why you get empty select result.

---

The only option when you **can have non-empty result** is when you add some extended ships into the list:

```
Structures.Add(new ResourceStructure());
```

Comment: Whoops! I made a mistake in my example. It was meant to be Structures.OfType<IResourceGatherer> rather than Ships.OfType<IResourceStorer>. I have fixed my code above, would you mind taking another look please?